# Linear algebra - solving equaltion

Tags: linear-algebra

## System -1

-x-2y = -2
x+2y=2

## System 2

x+3y=6
-x-3y=6

What is the solution to the system 1 and 2 separately?

- It has no solution
- Unique solution
- Infinitely many solution

I am seriously confused like if in sys 1 , i add both the eq then 0 = 0, does this mean it can have infinite solution and in sys 2, if i add both eq 0=16 , what does this mean?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the equation in the first system then you'll end up with $0=0$, that means' we have infinite number of solution, i.e. We'll have solution for every number.

If you do the same with the secon system you'll end up with $0=12$. That's contradiction and means that that system doesn't have a solutuon.